# C# Lambda Expression with Nullable Param Input

Tags: linq-to-entities

with the below, the model.Status and model.Source values may or may not be null. If null, I want the expression to pull all statuses/sources.  Is this possible with lambda because the below statement is not working?

```
var leads = db.CallCenterLead.Include("Profile").Include("Account")
.Where(x => x.DateSent >= model.DateFrom && x.DateSent <= model.DateTo 
&& ((model.Status != null && x.Status == model.Status) || (model.Status == null)) 
&& (model.Source != null && x.Source == model.Source)).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateSent).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm still getting used to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use an extension method, like this:

```
var leads = db.CallCenterLead.Include("Profile").Include("Account")
    .Where(x => x.DateSent >= model.DateFrom && x.DateSent <= model.DateTo)
    .WhereIf(model.Status != null, x.Status == model.Status)
    .WhereIf(model.Source != null, x.Source == model.Source)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateSent).ToList();
```

The extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
{
    return condition ? source.Where(predicate) : source;
}
```

The method adds the predicate if the condition is true. Otherwise it just returns the source as it were.

Comment: updated: var leads = db.CallCenterLead.Include("Profile").Include("Account")
                .Where(x => x.DateSent >= model.DateFrom && x.DateSent <= model.DateTo)
                .WhereIf(model.Status > 0, x => x.Status == model.Status)
                .WhereIf(model.Source != null, x => x.Source == model.Source)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateSent).ToList();